# clojure.test should assert the equality of two different float point number within a certain range

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I'm using [clojure.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) for unit testing.

Some of the tests fail because very close floating point numbers are considered differents.

```
expected: (= expected result)
  actual: (not (= 1.0 0.9999999999999998))

expected: (= expected result)
  actual: (not (= 0.5 0.4999999999999999))
```

I need to instruct clojure.test to understand that `(= 0.9999 1.0)` is true.

As an example, with NUnit I could use [Is.EqualTo().Within()](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/EqualConstraint) to achieve this.

**Note**

In my specific case, `1.0` and `0.999` are really the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding a good solution to this problem was one of the first questions I wrestled with when I started working with Clojure many years ago.  I created the `rel=` function [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#floating-point-number-comparison) for exactly this purpose:

```
  (rel= val1 val2 & opts)  
  "Returns true if 2 double-precision numbers are relatively equal, 
  else false. Relative equality is specified as either (1) the N 
  most significant digits are equal, or (2) the absolute difference 
  is less than a tolerance value.  Input values are coerced to double 
  before comparison."
```

here it is in action:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (is   (rel=   123450000   123456789  :digits 4 )) ; .12345 * 10^9
  (isnt (rel=   123450000   123456789  :digits 6 ))
  (is   (rel= 0.123450000 0.123456789  :digits 4 )) ; .12345 * 1
  (isnt (rel= 0.123450000 0.123456789  :digits 6 ))

  (is   (rel=  1  1.001  :tol 0.01   )) ; :tol value is absolute error
  (isnt (rel=  1  1.001  :tol 0.0001 )))
```

Comment: Too bad there is no solution for this inside clojure.core. The simplest solution for me was to write my own helper function.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything in clojure.test's API and didn't want other dependencies, so I wrote a function `close-to`:

```clj
(ns floats-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(defn abs
  [x]
  (max x (- x)))

(defn close-to
  [x y epsilon]
  (<= (abs (- x y)) epsilon))

(deftest floats...
  (testing "floats are equal"
    (is      (close-to 0.000000001 0.00000002  1e-7)))
  (testing "floats are equal (other direction)"
    (is      (close-to 0.000000002 0.00000001  1e-7)))
  (testing "floats aren't equal"
    (is (not (close-to 0.000000001 0.000001    1e-7))))
  (testing "floats aren't equal (other direction)"
    (is (not (close-to 0.000001    0.000000001 1e-7)))))
```